# Custom Close Button on Google Street Maps adding below Map as well

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the below code to add a Close Button to Google Street Maps.

The problem is, it is also adding the Close button below Google Map as well.
How can I stop the button been placed below the map.

```
function initialize() {
var myOptions = {
zoom: 6,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.976988, -8.327637),
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT,
    mapTypeIds: [
    google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    ]
}
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
infowindow.close();
});

// Create Close button
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.setAttribute('class','gbtn');
btn.setAttribute('id','button');
btn.innerHTML = '&times';

// Get close button and insert it into streetView
// #button can be any dom element
var closeButton = document.body.appendChild(btn),
    controlPosition = google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP;

// Assumes map has been initiated 
var streetView = map.getStreetView();

// Hide useless and tiny default close button
streetView.setOptions({ enableCloseButton: false });

// Add to street view
streetView.controls[controlPosition].push( closeButton );

// Listen for click event on custom button
// Can also be $(document).on('click') if using jQuery
google.maps.event.addDomListener(closeButton, 'click', function(){
    streetView.setVisible(false);
});

}
```

Comment: You are adding the button to the document body. `document.body.appendChild(btn)`

Comment: Hi, Have you a fix for this, please.